# Issue in renaming a folder in TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am trying to rename a folder in TortoiseSVN using SVN's rename option. But after the rename and checkin both the old and the new folders are present in the repository.

While renaming the folder, it is clearly showing as adding the new folder and deleting the old folder. But somehow it is retaining the old folder. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to commit the parent folder. A "rename" is actually a "copy" plus "delete" operation, and you committed the "copy" but not the "delete".

Recent versions of SVN prevent or warn against this. Consider upgrading.